# How to apt-get install a package for Ubuntu Quantal from Ubuntu Precise 12.04

Tags: ubuntu, postgresql, apt, openstack, postgis

On Ubuntu Precise 12.04, the package `osm2pgsql` is currently at `0.70.5+r25090-2ubuntu2`. However I need to install a newer version `0.80` but `apt-get update` does not provide the newer version.

**Question:** I found the `0.80` version in the Ubuntu quantal's repo at `https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/osm2pgsql/0.80.0+r27899-1ubuntu1`, is there any way to install this when I'm on Ubuntu 12.04?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't install packages for one version of Ubuntu on another version, or more accurately, you ***REALLY*** shouldn't.

You will create a mess of dependencies that will need to be resolved, and can easily dig down so far into your system that you wind up with an unstable or unusable machine as a result.

---

If you need a particular version of some package you have three real options:

1. Upgrade the OS to a release that distributes and supports the version of the package you need.
2. Find someone who has packaged the software for your platform/version (check [PPAs](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them))
3. Build it yourself and assemble a package.

Comment: backporting quite often is as easy as adding a new changelog entry in debian/changelog.  or via dch.